# Wrong approach to (-1)^(pi) problem. But Why?

Tags: complex-analysis

I understand the proper approach to solve $(-1)^{\pi}$ is to express -1 as the complex form ($-1=\cos(\pi)+ i*\sin(\pi)$) first, then proceed from there.

However, what if we say $(-1)^{\pi} = x$, and multiply both sides to get $(-1)^{\pi}\times(-1)^{\pi}$=$x^{2}$. Then solve it with $(1^{\pi})=x^{2}$. In this case, we would get x=1. I understand this approach is incorrect. But may I know why this method is wrong? Should we always use the complex approach when we see a negative number raise to power?

Many thanks!

Comment: Let $x=-1$. Then $x^2=(-1)^2=1$, thus $x=1$. _Always_ use the complex approach. $\left((-1)^{\pi}\right)^2=(-1)^{2\pi} \neq 1^{\pi}.$

Comment: $a^rb^r = (ab)^r$ is only an identity when $a, b \in \mathbb R_{\ge 0}$

Comment: I think a better approach might be $-1 = e^{(2n+1)\pi i}$ and so  $(-1)^\pi = e^{(2n+1)\pi^2 i}$ with integer $n$

Comment: Technically, $-1$ is, in complex form $-1+0i.$ What you are saying is that you need to write it in polar form, finding $(r,\theta)$ with $r\geq 0$ and $\theta\in(-\pi,\pi].$ and the complex number is $r(\cos \theta+i\sin \theta).$

Comment: Note that $1^{\pi}=1$ is not quite correct, since $1^{\pi}$ is *an infinite set*,which contains $1$ but contains $\exp(2\pi^2 i)$ for example where $\exp(z)$ is the usual entire exponential function $\Sigma{\frac{z^n}{n!}}$; more generally $1^n=1$ only for integral $n$, $1^q$ is a finite set for rational but not-integral $q$ with size the denominator of $q$ when written in lowest form, and $1^z$ is a countable infinite set otherwise

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying both sides of an equation by the same (non-zero) constant (in this case, $(-1)^\pi$) is valid. But that is not what you have done.

*Squaring* both sides of an equation, as you have done, always carries a risk of introducing new solutions that do not solve the original equation.

Answer (score 1):

This is because $(a)^b\times (a)^b\ne (a^2)^b$. For example let $$a=-1\\b={1\over 2}$$and let $$a^b=\sqrt{-1}=i$$then $$(a)^b\times (a)^b=i\times i=-1\ne 1=(-1\times -1)^{1\over 2}=(a^2)^b$$

Comment: The relation above has some validity as a set relation rather than a pointwise relation since $1^{\frac{1}{2}} = \pm 1$, so you get the relation {$\pm i$}{$\pm i$} = {$\pm 1$} which is true, though in general you may only get an inclusion